# Alternative to Matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm

Tags: python, matplotlib

1 - What is the **alternative** to **`Matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm`** that has been **deprecated** since Matplotlib 2.3.1?

2 - I still get `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.colors' has no attribute 'DivergingNorm'`, even though I am using Matplotlib version 2.2.4. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: [It is in 3.1.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm.html). You could copy [the source](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html#DivergingNorm) and define it for yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question for 2.2.4, but for the benefit of anyone who comes across this looking for the current (3.2.0) alternative: it is now [`matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html#matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm), the usage and documentation are identical to the [`matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm.html) from 3.1.0.